# Is using <div class="col-sm-6"> or <b-col sm="6"> the same?

Tags: bootstrap-vue

I just started looking into bootstrap-vue (and vue actually) and I noticed that `<b-col sm="6">` translates into the classic `<div class="col-sm-6">` so I wonder if there is any difference or advantages in using `<b-col sm="6">`.

Most web designers are confortable in using `<div class="col-sm-6">` so why asking them to switch to the other notation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<b-col>` (and the other layout helper components) are purely for convenience, as they require less typing (expecially for complex colums that have different width at different breakpoints).

They are written as Vue functional components (they keep no state information), so render fast.

You can be free to mix and match with regular html markup for layout, or not use them at all.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference but only more convenient to use.

By setting `sm="6"` as a property, you can more easily change the value (dynamic) without needing a jquery but purely a js function within Vue. With this you make full use of Vue which is a lot easier to see.

`:sm="getColSize"`
Can be anything you want. With classes i find it more effort.